# Ansible vault shows decrypted values if playbooks executed with debug mode

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-vault

I am using ansible vault to encrypt the password, but when I am using debug mode it shows the password as plain text. Consider below code

Generate ansible-vault encrypted password

```
ansible-vault encrypt_string 'abc123' --name ansible_ssh_pass > inventory/group_vars/all.yml
```

test.yml

```
- name: Vault test
  hosts: group_1
  tasks:
    - name: Read Json
      set_fact:
         version_file: "{{ lookup('template','template/test.j2') | to_json }}"
      run_once: true
```

inventory/hosts

```
[group_1]
xxx.xxx.com ansible_host=xx.xx.xx.xx ansible_user=root
xxx.xxx.com ansible_host=xx.xx.xx.xx ansible_user=root
```

template/test.j2

```
{ "host" : "xxx.xxx.com",
  "username" : "root",
  "password" : "{{ hostvars[groups['group_1'][0]]['ansible_ssh_pass'] }}"  }
```

Playbook execution

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/hosts test.yml --ask-vault-pass -vvv
```

Output

```
TASK [Read Json] ******************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /test/test.yml:5
ok: [xxx.xxx.com] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "version_file": "\"{ \\\"host\\\" : \\\"xxx.xxx.com\\\",\\n  \\\"username\\\" : \\\"root\\\",\\n  \\\"password\\\" : \\\"abc123\\n\\\"  }\\n\""
    },
    "changed": false,
    "failed": false
}
```

Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 3):

AFIK ansible vault encript passwords, although it can be visible if you use verbose options... For this you have to add to your playbook the option:

```
no_log: true
```

Take a look at this [link](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/18184) as they say:

*I don't believe Ansible keeps track of what came from the vault. To protect the data you can use* `no_log: true`

Answer (score 0):

To protect the data you can use `no_log: true`

Comment: Comments should be incomments box and once you have enough reputation you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be either a bug, an oversight, or a questionable design choice by the ansible maintainers.  I re-opened another issue here https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/82172 to prompt more discussion about this choice with the maintainers.

Also, no_log does not prevent verbose output from appearing, which will contain vault-encrypted variable values in plaintext.  Even if that did work, anyone who has access to the repository could just set no_log to false and have access to all vault-encrypted variables, completely circumventing any security provided by encrypting variables with ansible-vault.